# How do I configure Windows 10 to ignore a certain amount of mouse movement whlie clicking?

Tags: windows-10, mouse, boot-camp, imac, pixels

When I click, the mouse often moves a certain distance at the same time, so Windows 10 doesn't recognise it as a click. How do I increase the threshold in pixels that the mouse can move between the mouse down and up events while still being counted as a click?

As per other advice I found online, I increased DragWidth and DragHeight in the Registry, which solved the problem of a drag starting unintentionally. Now when I try to click, it doesn't drag, but it doesn't click, either

In case it matters, I'm using a Magic Mouse (not Magic Mouse 2) on an iMac 5K Late 2015 model running Windows 10 build 18363.535 with Boot Camp 6.0. I never had this problem in macOS, probably because macOS probably has a higher threshold to begin with, or the mouse is somehow optimised to work better with macOS.

So how do I increase the threshold in Windows, so that when I try to click, it's actually counted as a click?

Comment: This is common behavior if the sensitivity is set high and the mouse is not gripped optimally. I would start by lowering the sensitivty of the mouse and optionally enable mouse acceleration (make the pointer more precise)

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of other mouse settings in the Registry, such as the number of pixels of movement allowed on a double-click.

[image: Registry Mouse Settings]

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>, enter `rege`, select *regedit.exe* and accept UAC prompt.
- Move to (or copy/paste the following in the location bar):

  > HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Mouse
- Double-click a value such as *DoubleClickHeight* or *DoubleClickWidth* to change it.

Increasing the value allows the mouse or touchpad to wobble a bit more before the OS treats it as two separate clicks. This also means that small motions, e.g. while editing an image, may be ignored.

Change values in small increments, since a few pixels can make a big difference. You may need to reboot (or log off/on) before these changes take effect.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for single-click, not double. I looked at the others, but they seem to to about hover, speed, mouse trails, etc.